# Number of solutions to $n$-queens without anti-diagonal attacking?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we modify the classic $n$-queens problem where the queens can only attack along the diagonals traversing top-left to bottom-right (by symmetry it doesn't really matter which diagonal I guess). How many ways are there to place $n$ non-attacking such queens on an $n\times n$ board? Lower bounds are fine, but I'm hoping to find one as tight as possible.

Part two: suppose we just ask for $n$-rooks (so basically just permutations), but the rook closest to the bottom-right corner (by $\ell_1$ distance) is promoted to an anti-diagonal queen. Is it possible to say anything about this setup?

Comment: This is [A099152](https://oeis.org/A099152) in OEIS (see references). For part two, you can prune the $n$-rooks solutions (check the promoting diagonal), to get an idea of what's going on.